# How to create and write a file in a specific directory in PHP?

Tags: php, file

I want to create a file failure-log.log in a specific directory and write to it. Already got the directory path from database. The path is like this:

```
D:/folder-one/folder-two/
```

And my PHP code is executing in another directory like this:

```
C:/apache24/crawler/admin/startService.php
```

How can I create the file and write to it?

Comment: I notice that you want to write a file outside web root, which is *not* suggested due to security concern. If you insist, you must turn off [safe_mode](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode) or leave [doc_root](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.doc-root) to be empty in php.ini. Even you performed the above, you still need to give proper permission.

Comment: @Raptor Thanks for making me aware of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use absolute path(you can use realpath() on relative path as well to be sure about the path) and directory is writable

then

```
$dir = 'your/path';

file_put_contents($dir ."/failure-log.log", $contentOfFile);
```

if you want the content of file not to be removed everytime then I suggest using FILE_APPEND

```
file_put_contents($dir ."/failure-log.log", $contentOfFile, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.file-put-contents.php) method, like this:

```
$file ="D:/folder-one/folder-two/";
$current = file_get_contents($file); 
$current .= 'yourcontenthere';
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

U can send flags to `file_put_contents`, like `FILE_APPEND` :

```
$file ="D:/folder-one/folder-two/"; 
$text = 'yourcontenthere';
file_put_contents($file, $text, FILE_APPEND);
```

In that case u will not have to retrieve the old content, u can check and other flags in link above.

Also is good idea to check if file exists before that.

Comment: Have a look at `FILE_APPEND` in `file_put_contents()`

Comment: @NigelRen edited :) thank u!

Comment: Not recommended with large file. The function will copy the file into memory in order to copy the file to new location, which might hit PHP's max memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

Make that folder location writable for web server first. Then use below code to create file in that location.

```
$myfile = fopen("D:/folder-one/folder-two/file.log", "a") or die("Unable to open location for log file !");
$txt = "Log details goes here ...";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Write to files

   `$writeFile = @fopen('/path/to/save/file', 'w+');
   @fwrite($writeFile, $content);
   @fclose($writeFile);`

With:

```
w+: will create a new file if it does not exist and overwrite if it exists
a: append to file already exist
a+: append to file already exist and create a new file if it does not exist
```

2. If you load path directory from the database, you maybe need to create multi-directory

   `if( !is_dir($path) ) {
       mkdir($path, 0777, true);
   }`

With:

```
$path: path you were loaded from db
```

Comment: Never assign 777 permission to any folder or file; it is a common mistake, which will lead to security issues. If you want to create a folder with write permission for scripts, you use should 775 instead.

Comment: Why do you downvote me? @Raptor

Comment: Mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @Raptor I'm using the window OS, actually, I don't care your "lead to security issues" because mode permission doesn't works on Window. Additional, mode permission of mkdir default is 0777. You can check here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php.